# MySQL - fastest way to ALTER TABLE for InnoDB

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, alter-table, ddl

I have an InnoDB table that I want to alter. The table has ~80M rows, and quit a few indices.

I want to change the name of one of the columns and add a few more indices.

- What is the fastest way to do it (assuming I could suffer even downtime - the server is an unused slave)?
- Is a "plain" `alter table`, the fastest solution?

At this time, all I care about is speed :)

Comment: Please `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G`, show the column that needs to changed, the datatype of the column, and the new name for the column.

Comment: here it is: http://pastie.org/3078349 the column that need to be renamed is `sent_at` and to add it a few more indices

Comment: sent_at needs to be renamed to what ?

Comment: lets say: new_sent_at

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One sure way to speed up an ALTER TABLE is to remove unnecessary indexes

Here are the initial steps to load a new version of the table

```
CREATE TABLE s_relations_new LIKE s_relations;
#
# Drop Duplicate Indexes
#
ALTER TABLE s_relations_new
    DROP INDEX source_persona_index,
    DROP INDEX target_persona_index,
    DROP INDEX target_persona_relation_type_index
;
```

Please note the following:

- I dropped source_persona_index because it is the first column in 4 other indexes

  - unique_target_persona
  - unique_target_object
  - source_and_target_object_index
  - source_target_persona_index
- I dropped target_persona_index because it is the first column in 2 other indexes

  - target_persona_relation_type_index
  - target_persona_relation_type_message_id_index
- I dropped target_persona_relation_type_index because the first 2 columns are also in target_persona_relation_type_message_id_index

OK That takes care of unnecessary indexes. Are there any indexes that have low cardinality? Here is the way to determine that:

Run the following queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sent_at)               FROM s_relations;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT message_id)            FROM s_relations;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT target_object_id)      FROM s_relations;
```

According to your question, there are about 80,000,000 rows. As a rule of thumb, the MySQL Query Optimizer will not use an index if the cardinality of the selected columns is greater that 5% of the table row count. In this case, that would be 4,000,000.

- If `COUNT(DISTINCT sent_at)` > 4,000,000

  - then `ALTER TABLE s_relations_new
    DROP INDEX sent_at_index;`
- If `COUNT(DISTINCT message_id)` > 4,000,000

  - then `ALTER TABLE s_relations_new
    DROP INDEX message_id_index;`
- If `COUNT(DISTINCT target_object_id)` > 4,000,000

  - then `ALTER TABLE s_relations_new
    DROP INDEX target_object_index;`

Once the usefulness or uselessness of those indexes have been determined, you can reload the data

```
#
# Change the Column Name
# Load the Table
#
ALTER TABLE s_relations_new CHANGE sent_at sent_at_new int(11) DEFAULT NULL;
INSERT INTO s_relations_new SELECT * FROM s_relations;
```

That's it, right? NOPE !!!

If your website has been up this whole time, there may have INSERTs running against s_relations during the loading of s_relations_new. How can you retrieve those missing rows?

Go find the maximum id in s_relations_new and append everything after that ID from s_relations. To assure that the table is frozen and used only for this update, you must have a little downtime for the sake of getting those last rows that were inserted into s_relation_new. Here is what you do:

In the OS, restart mysql so that no one else can log in but root@localhost (disables TCP/IP):

```
$ service mysql restart --skip-networking
```

Next, login to mysql and load those last rows:

```
mysql> SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxidnew FROM s_relations_new;
mysql> INSERT INTO s_relations_new SELECT * FROM s_relations WHERE id > @maxidnew;
mysql> ALTER TABLE s_relations RENAME s_relations_old;
mysql> ALTER TABLE s_relations_new RENAME s_relations;
```

Then, restart mysql normally

```
$ service mysql restart
```

Now, if you cannot take mysql down, you will have to do a bait-and-switch on s_relations. Just login to mysql and do the following:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE s_relations RENAME s_relations_old;
mysql> SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxidnew FROM s_relations_new;
mysql> INSERT INTO s_relations_new SELECT * FROM s_relations_old WHERE id > @maxidnew;
mysql> ALTER TABLE s_relations_new RENAME s_relations;
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : Once you are satisfied with this operation, you can drop the old table at your earliest convenience:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE s_relations_old;
```

Answer (score 12):

The correct answer depends on the version of the MySQL engine you're using.

If using 5.6+, renames and adding/removing indices are performed [online](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/online_alter_table_in_mysql), i.e. without copying all the table's data.

Just use `ALTER TABLE` as usual, it'll be mostly instant for renames and index drops, and reasonably fast for index addition (as fast as reading all the table once).

If using 5.1+, and the InnoDB plugin is enabled, adding/removing indices will be online as well. Not sure about renames.

If using older version, `ALTER TABLE` is still the fastest—but will probably be horribly slow because *all of your data* will be re-inserted to a temporary table under the hood.

Finally, time for myth debunking.
Unfortunately I don't have enough karma here to comment on answers, but I feel it's important to correct the most voted answer. This is **wrong**:

> As a rule of thumb, the MySQL Query Optimizer will not use an index if the cardinality of the selected columns is greater that 5% of the table row count

It's actually the [other way around](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html).

Indices are useful to select *few* rows, so it's important they have *high* cardinality, which means many distinct values and statistically few rows with the same value.

Comment: Link to [InnoDB plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/index.html) documentation (couldn't paste due to rep limits).

Comment: On MySQL 5.5 I found `RENAME TABLE` instant (as expected) but a `CHANGE COLUMN` to rename the primary key did a full copy... 7 hours! Possibly only because it was the primary key? Not good.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Maria DB 10.1.12, then after reading the documentation I found that there is an option to perform the operation "in-place" which eliminates the copy of the table. With this option the alter table is very fast. In my case it was:

```
alter table user add column (resettoken varchar(256),
  resettoken_date date, resettoken_count int), algorithm=inplace;
```

this is very fast. Without the algorithm option it would never terminate.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/

Answer (score 0):

For the column rename,

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE columnname newcolumnname datatype;
```

should be fine and not carry any downtime.

For the indexes the CREATE INDEX statement will lock the table.  If it's a unused slave as you mentioned, that's not an issue.

One other option would be to create a brand new table that has the proper column names and indexes.  Then you could copy all the data into it, then execute a series of

```
BEGIN TRAN;
ALTER TABLE RENAME tablename tablenameold;
ALTER TABLE RENAME newtablename tablename;
DROP TABLE tablenameold;
COMMIT TRAN;
```

This would minimize the downtime at the cost of temporarily using twice the space.

Comment: DDL in MySQL is not transactional. Each DDL statement triggers a COMMIT. I wrote about this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36799/877

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem too and I used this SQL:

```
/*on créé la table COPY SANS les nouveaux champs et SANS les FKs */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prestations_copy LIKE prestations;

/* on supprime les FKs de la table actuelle */
ALTER TABLE `prestations`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_prestations_pres_promos`,
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_prestations_activites`;

/* on remet les FKs sur la table copy */
ALTER TABLE prestations_copy 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_prestations_activites` FOREIGN KEY (`act_id`) REFERENCES `activites` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_prestations_pres_promos` FOREIGN KEY (`presp_id`) REFERENCES `pres_promos` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;

/* On fait le transfert des données de la table actuelle vers la copy, ATTENTION: il faut le même nombre de colonnes */
INSERT INTO prestations_copy
SELECT * FROM prestations;

/* On modifie notre table copy de la façon que l'on souhaite */
ALTER TABLE `prestations_copy`
    ADD COLUMN `seo_mot_clef` VARCHAR(50) NULL;

/* on supprime la table actuelle et renome la copy avec le bon nom de table */
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE prestations;
RENAME TABLE prestations_copy TO prestations;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I hope it could help someone

Regards,

Will