# MySQL backup InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, windows, mysqldump

I have a VoIP server running 24x7. At low peak hour at lease 150+ users are connected. My server has MySQL running with InnoDB engine on Windows 2008 platform. I like to take at least 2 times full database backup without shutting down my service.

As per Peter Zaitsev - the founder of percona, mysqldump –single-transaction is not always good.

[read here if you are interested](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/best-kept-mysqldump-secret/)

As I'm not a DBA, I like to know in my scenario, which would be best solution to take a database backup?

Thanks,

Comment: It's possible to configure database replication (master/slave) and then create backup on slave server at any time.

Answer (score 2):

As your link points out, `ALTER TABLE` can break a transaction

In fact, according to Page 418 Paragraph 3 of [MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[image: sx]

the following commands can break a transaction

- `ALTER TABLE`
- `BEGIN`
- `CREATE INDEX`
- `DROP DATABASE`
- `DROP INDEX`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `RENAME TABLE`
- `TRUNCATE TABLE`
- `LOCK TABLES`
- `UNLOCK TABLES`
- `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1`
- `START TRANSACTION`

Thus, you cannot run any of these and have a stable mysqldump

## SUGGESTION

You badly need to create a MySQL Replication setup

That way, the Master and stay up 24/7.

On the Slave, you can do the following:

- `STOP SLAVE;`
- `mysqldump --single-transaction`
- `START SLAVE;`

and never disturb the Master.

## CAVEAT

Since setting up Replication requires a stable mysqldump, you may need downtime for the one-time setup. My answer would be a lot different if your MySQL was in Linux.