# Conditions that can make a MySQL COMMIT query fail?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, transaction

I have an application where I run an explicit `COMMIT` query on a MySQL standalone server

```sql
COMMIT;
```

The query works as expected in the vast majority of cases, but sometimes the query seems successful but at the same time seems not to commit the transaction to the DB.

So I was digging into the possibility that a `COMMIT` query could fail. I found this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960189/can-a-commit-statement-in-sql-ever-fail-how

but on the official [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) never mentions that a `COMMIT` can fail.

I want to understand in which conditions a commit query can fail and how to reproduce it, possibly supported by official doc pages.

Comment: Did you issue a START TRANSACTION? Is there anything in the logs? Do you have the proper PRIVs? Can we see the query?

Comment: Yes, the transaction is wrapped with the `START TANSACTION` query. I can't access mysql's logs. The event described is not systematic, it happens only *sometimes*

Comment: If COMMIT fails, it will just like any other statements, emit an error. If your application is throwing away the error, it will not show what the problem is/was. MySQL logs are OK, but your application's log is probably more important here. Also, maybe your transaction succeeds, not changing anything?

Comment: Is this a standalone server?  Or part of some kind of cluster?

Comment: Soon after it happens, run `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;` and post the results here.

Comment: Also check the return code from the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not on the `COMMIT` query, the problem was that during that transaction an **implicit rollback** happens.

As the documentation says, this can happen if a [deadlock occures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-handling.html) during the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how you setup the transaction.

If you have `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT;` surrounding a series of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries, there are some commands that trigger an implicit commit:

- ALTER TABLE
- CREATE INDEX
- DROP DATABASE
- DROP INDEX
- DROP TABLE
- RENAME TABLE
- TRUNCATE TABLE
- LOCK TABLES
- UNLOCK TABLES
- SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1
- BEGIN (can break another `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION`)
- START TRANSACTION (can break another `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN`)

I have mentioned this before in the DBA StackExchange

- `Mar 06, 2018` : [Can you rollback a query in state 'committing alter table to storage engine'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199491/can-you-rollback-a-query-in-state-committing-alter-table-to-storage-engine/199507#199507)
- `Aug 21, 2015` : [Transactional DDL workflow for MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90794/transactional-ddl-workflow-for-mysql/111874#111874)
- `Feb 12, 2014` : [row locking within ACID transaction innodb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/row-locking-within-acid-transaction-innodb/58712#58712)
- `Mar 15, 2013` : [MySQL backup InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36797/mysql-backup-innodb/36799#36799)

You can see the [latest list of commands that trigger implicit commits in the MySQL 5.7 Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html). Why consider implicit commits ? Data may commit out of context with other data too soon or too late.

Aside from these commands, terminating a DB Connection will implicitly rollback a transaction. You should monitor the status variables [Aborted_connects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) and [Aborted_clients](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_clients) to see if DB Connections are failing on entry or in session.

Comment: Hi, I am reading that [deadlocks can cause implicit rollbacks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-handling.html)